# changing the look of the forum module in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, forum

I've been tasked with maintaining a site built in Drupal 7. I don't know Drupal that well, but the site already exists and I've been able to figure out everything else so far. They wanted a forum, so I'm using the basic forum module, which seems to work fine. However, I cannot figure out how to change the look of the forum using the wsiwyg tools.

I can create a view that lists the forum topics, but I cannot make one that lists the forums themselves, nor can I find another way to change the styling whatsoever. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The styling will be done with CSS, Drupal's core developers tend to put a lot (and I mean a lot!) of class names/div wrappers around everything so that anyone and his dog can easily change the styling.

Forums in Drupal 7 are a taxonomy term, part of a vocabulary, so bear that in mind when you're trying to build your view. They're not nodes.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That does it! Thanks so much.